# SCNMatrix4 vs simd - Column Major or Row Major?

Tags: xcode, scenekit, arkit

Does `SCNMatrix4` follow column major or row major convention? Consider the following:

```
func makeTranslationMatrix(tx: Float, ty: Float, tz: Float) -> simd_float4x4 {
    var matrix = matrix_identity_float4x4

    matrix[3, 0] = tx
    matrix[3, 1] = ty
    matrix[3, 2] = tz

    return matrix
}

var T1 = makeTranslationMatrix(tx: 1, ty: 2, tz: 3)
print(T1.columns.0)
print(T1.columns.1) 
print(T1.columns.2) 
print(T1.columns.3) 
/*
T1
float4(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0)
float4(0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0)
float4(0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0)
float4(1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 1.0)
*/

var sceneT1 = SCNMatrix4MakeTranslation(1, 2, 3)
print("\(sceneT1.m11), \(sceneT1.m12), \(sceneT1.m13), \(sceneT1.m14)")
print("\(sceneT1.m21), \(sceneT1.m22), \(sceneT1.m23), \(sceneT1.m24)")
print("\(sceneT1.m31), \(sceneT1.m32), \(sceneT1.m33), \(sceneT1.m34)")
print("\(sceneT1.m41), \(sceneT1.m42), \(sceneT1.m43), \(sceneT1.m44)")
/*
sceneT1
1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0
0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0
0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0
1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 1.0
*/
```

As you can see, the translation values for SCNMatrix4 are stored in m41, m42, m43 - in the 4th column. It may be possible that these values are stored in m41, m42, m43 due to the matrix being transposed and then they actually store the translation values in the 4th row.

I can't find a definite piece of information that will state the exact convention being used. Does `m41` refer to fourth column, first row or fourth row, first column?

Answer (score 0):

The translation matrix tells you whether it is row or column major. Translation happens at the end of each row. Since the translation appears at the bottom "row" when printed out, each row represents a column.

TL;DR. It uses Column Major storage.